# Is it possible to stream audio via Google Assistant in the Netherlands?

Tags: streaming, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I want to stream audio using the [actions-on-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) and I was wondering if this already is possible.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452906/is-it-possible-to-play-audio-file-or-stream) where it is mentioned that it is not possible.
But this is already a year old so I was wondering if it already is possible and if not when it will be possible.

I found this [page](https://developers.google.com/actions/media/reference/data-specification/radiostations-specification) but it is not really clear to me if I can use this for the google assistant.

Comment: Do you want to stream live audio, or a pre-recorded clip?

Comment: I want to stream live audio

Comment: That is still not supported on the platform.

Comment: ok, thanks for you answer. Any idea if this will be possible in the near future?

Comment: I don't have a timeline that I can share.