# Is there a way to create an "Action on Google" that answers to "Google play X radio" and to actually play a stream?

Tags: google-home

I work for a new radio station that broadcasts terrestrial (in FM). We are trying to become available on Google Home with "Ok Google, play *Our Radio*".  Currently if you try to play some other radio Google Home actually plays from TuneIn. The problem is that TuneIn does not accept new radio listings, so I am trying to find a workaround.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell Actions on Google to stream audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048385/how-can-i-tell-actions-on-google-to-stream-audio)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [partner with Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/media/radiostations-specification) to make your stream available.