# Google Action should play radio stream

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I need to develop a Google Action which streams an audio/radio stream.

i thought about media response. 
But the documentation says: "Audio for playback must be in a correctly formatted .mp3 file. Live streaming is not supported."

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses)

Can someone give me an hint, what i have to do to stream an audio-stream? i found a german google action "baden fm" which streams their radio. But not sure how they do it.

Kind Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 4):

The only ways to do this currently:

- Stream it in chunks of MP3 files, using the callback at the end of streaming to stream the next chunk
- Getting listed on TuneIn, Radio.com or iHeartRadio.  From observation, Baden FM seems to be using TuneIn
- Through an App Action
- Use a Web site link that starts streaming via BrowseCarousel or Button

Last 2 options are not helpful if you're going after non-browser-enabled devices.

Also saw this thread which has some insight on MP3 size/duration: [How can I tell Actions on Google to stream audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048385/how-can-i-tell-actions-on-google-to-stream-audio)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i use the "TuneIn" variant, i doesn't have a google-action. So i'm not be able to implement additional intents like: 
- Whats currently playing? etc?

correct? Or can i start tune-in streams from my google action?

Answer (score 1):

Google Actions do not currently support live audio streaming. I'm in contact with them but it seems they have no ETA to support this.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful doing so with an mp3 live stream:

NPR: `https://npr-ice.streamguys1.com/live.mp3?ck=1597372625378`

but not with mpd

BBC test stream: `https://rdmedia.bbc.co.uk/dash/ondemand/testcard/1/client_manifest-audio.mpd`

or with the HLS that my company uses ( `.m3u8`, can't publish the link publicly )

Note: added links as text/code since I'm not sure whether their companies policies are cool with them being indexed.